# Removing additional trailing backslash with .htacess – domain.com/page//

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have content that can display with a double-slash:
domain.com/folder/name//

Obviously this is not ideal.

I want to create a .htaccess 301 rewrite that removes the additional trailing slash:
domain.com/folder/name/

I came-up with:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)// /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Though no-dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match `//` in `RewriteRule` since Apache strips it to single there.

Use `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+(.*?)/+(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```